# Effect of Width on Plasma Beam Weapons

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, weapons

As an example of a plasma beam: in the Star Wars franchise, lightsabers are used as the multipurpose weapons of Jedi. The Jedi lightsabers have beams which seem to have be around 1 to 2 inches in diameter. They are used to deflect lasers, deflect other lightsabers, and to cut through a large variety of materials. In the franchise, the Jedi are also capable of adjusting the length of the saber, as well as the shape of the tip, but the width adjustment is not mentioned.

Some cases I can think of for variable adjustment of are adjusting the beam width to become closer to a shield in width to protect against laser barrages, adjusting it to be closer to a rapier for precise cutting operations, and perhaps even adjusting the width to allow the weapon to target gaps in the enemy’s armour.

Assume that operation time of the bean is not indefinite. A beam on a personal weapon can only be maintained for eight hours per energy cell. Increasing the surface area of the beam will increase the required energy output due to dissipation exponentially. Eg, if the surface area is doubled, the operation time will be 1/4th.

If in a world, a lot of warriors do employ the beams in weapons for combat, would a variable width plasma beam have an advantage over an invariable one? Also, what width is suitable for incapacitating other lifeforms?

If anyone is interested, [here](https://www.space.com/31361-building-a-real-lightsaber.html) is how such a weapon would employ the beam, using plasma contained with magnetic fields, as stated by Halfthawed below.

Comment: Lightsabers are more or less on the far side of 'hard vs soft' when it comes to science fiction, so the better question is just 'how effective will it be', and just handwave how the build works. For instance, Kylo Ren's saber-hilt monstrosity thing goes against the previously established rules for building sabers, and nobody cared.

Comment: @Halfthawed good point. Will revise, it is rather difficult to understand the specific mechanics of a laser sabre

Comment: Lightsabers are actually plasma swords bound in magnetic fields these days, which they swapped to when they realized how impractical a laser sword would be. Plasma swords aren't *much* better, but it's an improvement at least.

Comment: @Halfthawed I did a search based on that, and there were some nice articles on how to replicate it, thanks for the info :)

Comment: The probability of high energy photon-photon collision scales according to the width but at macroscopic scale that's margin becomes less significant unless you want to deflect laser beam.

Comment: Why make it swordlike at all? Just have a great big ball-o-death with a handle, point it in the general direction of your enemies and walk forwards. It'll kill anyone you hit with it, it just won't dice them up in a cinematically satisfying way.

Comment: I mean unless your beam weapons are also inexplicably slowed down to the point that they are easily trackable with the naked eye good luck deflecting something that should move at light speed

Comment: @StarfishPrime good point, the beam can be easily attached to a long spear to extend the reach too, although the energy output in such a case would definitely be more.

Comment: @Enthus3d it already requires magical super efficient super dense super powerful energy sources. Seems trivial to scale that up a bit. That's the problem with under constrained magic; you can break all sorts of stuff with it.

Comment: @BKlassen as in the Discworld, the photons of starwars travel at the speed of plot.

Comment: @StarfishPrime good point. I will add more constraints to my question

Comment: The magnetic containment fields just don't work within current understanding of physics.  It's soft sci-fi that isn't science based.  A plasma sword will have to work exactly how the _story_ demands, since they don't work at all outside of a narrative.  Obviously some great stories can be written with them included in the universe, but they are as magical as The Force, The Schwartz, and any other telekinetic powers used in the various franchises that use plasma weapons.  (Side note: Why wouldn't we consider the Gungan's plasma shields to be the "wide beam" interpretation of the tech?)

Comment: Just to know why plasma swords are a bad idea: 1. They burn your eyeballs to crisps 2. They burn you to crisps just by holding them close 3. Hitting anything with it will result in an explosion, which is pretty deadly to the wielder 4. If Palpatine doesn't kill Kylo, the electricity bills will.

Comment: 'adjusting the width to allow the weapon to target gaps in the enemy’s armour' Storm troopers wear armor but it doesn't really seem to do anything, so adjusting for gaps would be a waste of time. Like squishing a bug in the structurally weakest point of its carapace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to base this answer on how lightsabers appear to work in Star Wars - not on the actual physics of plasma constrained within magnetic fields. These two different lightsaber concepts produce drastically different results - and the "real" version linked in the question is not an effective weapon.

### Width doesn't matter for melee

The [Star Wars wiki](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Lightsaber-resistant_materials) says that aside from a few special substances, lightsabers can cut through anything. If lightsabers were relatively weak, and you had to target gaps in armor, greater width would allow you to do more damage. But we'll only need to do slashing, so we don't need to poke wide holes at all. We could hypothetically enter combat with a saber of infinitely small radius and it would be no different from using a 1-inch saber because we're cutting, not stabbing.

### Width does matter when cutting through metal

We know that lightsabers [take longer to cut metal than flesh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K48M2S7bkSA), which is important when using them to cut through thick armor, tanks, or buildings. A thick blade would leave a larger hole, separating dense material more effectively. If you cut through a brick wall with an infinitely thin blade, the "hole" you cut would be difficult to displace. If the shape you cut had a one-inch margin of melted / evaporated material, entry would be easier. A thicker blade might also get hotter - or at least distribute more heat, because a wider cylinder would have a larger surface area. Therefore, thickness might mean faster melting.

### Width does matter for ranged combat

A thin blade would be useless at deflecting lasers; once again, surface area is the key factor here. A wider blade has more surface, so it works as a better shield to intercept a thin ray of light. Using a lightsaber to deflect lasers doesn't make a lot of sense in the first place, assuming that "lasers" move at the speed of light and thus can't be reacted to. You would need a serious Jedi-reaction speed to notice a laser - or even a bullet - in time to deflect it like a baseball.

Comment: As it was shown in VII episode when Kyle time-stops blaster shot - blasters are not lasers. And they are moving at much lower than bullet speed (about 20-50 m/s). MG 42 would be a devastating uber-anti-infantry deathbringer in a galaxy far, far away!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out some of my incorrect assumptions about blaster fire; I'm still getting into the sci-fi universe. Good answer overall, pointing out the various scenarios of useful beam-width. Thanks!